# Call to JNI_CreateJavaVM() crashes on Java 1.7.0_40

Tags: java, c++, crash, java-native-interface

The following code succeeds most of the time, but sometimes causes the program to crash (all threads exiting with code 1).

```
string classpath;
JavaVMOption options[6];

std::string heapOptionString = "-Xms500m"; //Important !!! please adjust when needed, default is 1GB of RAM usage = "-Xms1g"
std::string jmxOptionString = "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote";
std::string unlockCFOptionString = "-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures";
std::string flightRecOptionString = "-XX:+FlightRecorder";
std::string useGC1 = "-XX:+UseG1GC";

options[0].optionString = new char[classpath.size()+1];
strcpy_s(options[0].optionString, classpath.size()+1,classpath.c_str());
options[1].optionString = new char[heapOptionString.size()+1];
strcpy_s(options[1].optionString, heapOptionString.size()+1,heapOptionString.c_str());
options[2].optionString = new char[jmxOptionString.size()+1];
strcpy_s(options[2].optionString, jmxOptionString.size()+1, jmxOptionString.c_str());
options[3].optionString = new char[unlockCFOptionString.size()+1];
strcpy_s(options[3].optionString, unlockCFOptionString.size()+1, unlockCFOptionString.c_str());
options[4].optionString = new char[flightRecOptionString.size()+1];
strcpy_s(options[4].optionString, flightRecOptionString.size()+1, flightRecOptionString.c_str());
options[5].optionString = new char[useGC1.size()+1];
strcpy_s(options[5].optionString, useGC1.size()+1, useGC1.c_str());

vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 6;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

It is inconsistent - sometimes I am able to run my application multiple times during the day, but once the problem appears - it crashes every time and the only way to resolve it is to log off and log in again (some java service hanging in memory?).

I've checked other questions on SO, relating to the creation of VM trough JNI, but they seem to be related to other causes (old bugs in Java 1.6 that are supposed to be fixed now) or have different circumstances - i.e. 100% reproducible crash.

EDIT: I should also mention, that this code is part of a method in a class, that is essentially a wrapper over a JAVA library that I am using. Also it is executed from non-main thread and there is no prior calls to JNI whatsoever.

Comment: I don't see where `classpath` was declared.  Also, there are less error-prone ways to set up the options.  A string array and loop would have been better.  `string allopts[] = {classpath, heapOptionString, jmxOptionString...etc}; ... for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(allopts)/sizeof(allopts[0]); ++i ) { options[i].optionString = new char[allopts[i].size()+1]; strcpy_s(options[i].optionString, allopts[i].size()+1, allopts[i].c_str()); }`

Comment: Thanks @PaulMcKenzie, classpath is a private member of the class this method is a member of. I've included it in the example code above.